# hql join could not resolve property; use two tables mapping

Tags: java, join, mapping, hql, one-to-many

I have 2 tables prod (goods) with

```
> id, catid(category), name, price
```

And cat

```
> with id, catname.
```

I wanna select like this in SQL

```
>  select * from cat join prod on cat.id=prod.catid where
> cat.name='catname';
```

My query is;

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from prod pr join pr.cat ct with pr.catid=ct.id where ct.name=?");
```

I have

> could not resolve property: cat of: goods.prod [from goods.prod pr
>   join pr.cat ct with pr.catid=ct.id where ct.name=?]

error
and in indexservice.java i have import goods.cat unused. But why? If i wrote function to use goods.prod that imports goods.cat.
Ok. that was with no mapping. I add this in cat.java

```
**cat.java**

package goods;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import goods.prod;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="cat")


public class cat implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;

      @Id @GeneratedValue 
      @Column(name="id")
      @OneToMany
      @JoinColumn(name="catid", referencedColumnName="id")
      private List<prod> prods;

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4147058093508047162L;

    private String Name;

    public cat() {
    }

    public cat(int id, String Name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.Name = Name;
    }


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

     public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    }
```

**prod.java**

```
package goods;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumns;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import goods.cat;

import java.io.Serializable;


@Entity
@Table(name = "prod")

public class prod implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue 
    @Column(name = "catid")

    private Long id;

    private Integer catid;

    private String name;
    private Integer price;


    public prod() {
    }

    public prod(Long id, Integer catid, String name, Integer price) {
        this.id = id;
        this.catid = catid;
        this.name = name ;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Long getid() {
        return id;
    }

     public void setid(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getcatid() {
        return catid;
    }
    public void setcatid(Integer catid) {
        this.catid = catid;
    }

    public String getname() {
        return name;
    }    
    public void setname(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getprice() {
        return price;
    }   
    public void setprice(Integer price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    }
```

**IndexService.java**

```
import goods.prod;
import goods.cat;
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public  static ArrayList<prod> getListOfProds(String catname,String name,Integer pricel, Integer priceh){
        ArrayList<prod> list = new ArrayList<prod>();
        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;        
        try {
            tx = session.getTransaction();
            tx.begin();
            Query query = session.createQuery("from prod pr join pr.cat ct with pr.catid=ct.id where ct.name=?");
            //Query query = session.createQuery("from prod pr join pr.cat ct with pr.catid=ct.id where ct.name=?");
            query.setString(0, catname);
            //query.setInteger(1, pricel);
            //query.setInteger(2, priceh);
            list = (ArrayList<prod>) query.list(); 

            tx.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `prod` class (defined in `prod.java`) you have not mapped a field cat (as object type `cat`), you have mapped only catId as integer.

So you can't use a join like yours.

You can re-write your query like this:

```
FROM prod pr, cat ct
WHERE pr.catid = ct.id
AND ct.name = ?
```

Comment: Thanks but how can I map object cat? cat is not mapped [FROM goods.prod pr, cat ct WHERE pr.catid = ct.id AND ct.name = ?]

Comment: Instead of catId as property of your prod class, use a private cat cat;

Comment: How can I use instead of catid iff i have this in db? I remove catid and setters/getters and change it to private  cat cat/ I get Unknown column 'prod0_.cat' in 'field list'

Comment: I post question in another post

Comment: You have a catid field on your db but you can map your property with many-to-one relation

Answer (score 0):

**manytoone** 
another variant

public class prod implements Serializable {

```
@Id @GeneratedValue 
@Column(name = "catid")
@ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="cat", referencedColumnName="id")
 // private Integer catid;
private Long id;
private cat cat; 
private String name;
private Integer price;
```

> @Column(s) not allowed on a @ManyToOne property: goods.prod.id